# Login & Signup iOS Swift - Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to create login and signup functions within Swift using Core Data.

This is my code to store the data in the signupVC;

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newUser.setValue(txtUsername.text, forKey: "username")
    newUser.setValue(txtPassword.text, forKey: "password")
    newUser.setValue(txtEmailAdd.text, forKey: "email")

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {}

    print(newUser)
    print("Object Saved.")
```

This is the code in the LoginVC;

```
@IBAction func signinTapp(sender: UIButton) {

    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "" + txtUsername.text!)

    let results:NSArray = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)



    if(results.count > 1){
        let res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
        txtUsername.text = res.valueForKey("username") as! String
        txtPassword.text = res.valueForKey("password") as! String

        //for res in results {
         //   print(res)


    }else{
        print("Incorrect username and password")
    }


}
```

Can anyone please advise my the best way forward? - I just need to retrieve  the saved core data and check if it matches.

Here is my Core Data model:

[image: Here is my Core Data model]

Answer (score 1):

look into below code

```
   func CheckForUserNameAndPasswordMatch (userName : String, password : String) ->Bool
    {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        var predicate = NSPredicate (format:"userName = %@" ,userName)
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest ( entityName: "UserEntity")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        var error : NSError? = nil
        var fetchRecult = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
        if fetchRecult?.count>0
        {
            var objectEntity : UserEntity = fetchRecult?.first as! UserEntity
            if objectEntity.userName == userName && objectEntity.password == password
            {
                return true   // Entered Username & password matched 
            }
            else
            {
                return false  //Wrong password/username
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Moreover it would not be good to save password in device if you are working on any enterprise product.

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorials or best practices on how to create a user login and signup interface on Swift with a database?

Comment: You have to implement your logic according to your app but for practice you can visit http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates  and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-21505 . moreover for every new signup you have to check your database for new username. If username already exist then show alert to user that name already exist.

Comment: Thanks. When adding your code above on this line; var objectEntity : UserEntity = fetchRecult?.first as! UserEntity ... i get undeclared type of UserEntity

Comment: UserEntity is my ManagedObjectSubclass name. Place here your sub class name.

Answer (score 1):

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var txt_username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt_password: UITextField!

var result = NSArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func Log_in(_ sender: Any)
{
    if txt_username.text == "" && txt_password.text == ""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Please enter all the fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else

    {

        self.CheckForUserNameAndPasswordMatch(username : txt_username.text! as String, password : txt_password.text! as String)


    }

}

func CheckForUserNameAndPasswordMatch( username: String, password : String)
{
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LoginDetails")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", username)

    fetchrequest.predicate = predicate
    do
    {
        result = try context.fetch(fetchrequest) as NSArray

        if result.count>0
        {
            let objectentity = result.firstObject as! LoginDetails

            if objectentity.username == username && objectentity.password == password
            {
                print("Login Succesfully")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Wrong username or password !!!")
            }
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        let fetch_error = error as NSError
        print("error", fetch_error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

}

Registration page
==================>

import UIKit
import CoreData

class RegistrationPage: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var txt_user: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt_mailid: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt_pwd: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt_cpwd: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var txt_phone: UITextField!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func register(_ sender: Any)
{
    if txt_user.text == "" || txt_mailid.text == "" || txt_pwd.text == "" || txt_cpwd.text == "" || txt_phone.text == ""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Its Mandatort to enter all the fields", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else if (txt_pwd.text != txt_cpwd.text)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Password does not match", preferredStyle: .alert
        )

        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else
    {
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let new_user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "LoginDetails", into: context)

        new_user.setValue(txt_user.text, forKey: "username")
        new_user.setValue(txt_mailid.text, forKey: "mailid")
        new_user.setValue(txt_pwd.text, forKey: "password")
        new_user.setValue(txt_phone.text, forKey: "phone")

        do
        {
            try context.save()
            print("Registered  Sucessfully")
        }
        catch
        {
            let Fetcherror = error as NSError
            print("error", Fetcherror.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `username` unique as per database constraint? Then, you will never get more than one result from the fetch.

If you use

```
if let user = results.first where
   user.pass == (passField.text ?? "") {
// login
 }
else {
// no login
}
```

you'd be better of.

Also, do not set the field's from the db; check if they are equal.

Also, please realize that such a sign-up will be valid only on a per-app-installation basis.

For production security, store only hashes of passwords.

Comment: For now i am creating a prototype, so i will store the password as a hash later & yes username is unique.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to make a user login system using core data

First you have to create a project and include core data in it. Then you have to add to the .xcdatamodeld file an entity with some attributes.
Here is a picture of how does the file looks like:

[CoreData.xcdatamodeld File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw7Fu.png)

Here is the example code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)

        newUser.setValue("Joe", forKey: "username")
        newUser.setValue("JoeTheLazy", forKey: "password")
        newUser.setValue(48, forKey: "age")


        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")


        } catch {

            print ( "Some Error has been Detected")
        }


        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let reusutls = try context.fetch(request)
            if reusutls.count > 0 {

                for r in reusutls as! [NSManagedObject]
                {

                    if let username  = r.value(forKey: "username") as? String
                    {print(username)}

                }

            }
            else {print("Cannot fetch results")

            }
        }
        catch {

            print("error")

        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var usrName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passWord: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var showList: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorText: UILabel!
    @IBAction func tryLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let x = usrName.text
        let y = passWord.text
        if (x! == "" || y! == "")
        {
            print ("I am here")

            errorText.text = "user name or password empty "
        }
        let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", usrName.text!)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)

            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {

                let passwordFromData = data.value(forKey: "password") as! String
                if y! == passwordFromData
                {
                errorText.text = " You have been Granted Access!"
            }
        }
        }catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func ShowData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var listTprint = ""
        let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let reusutls = try context.fetch(request)
            if reusutls.count > 0 {
                for r in reusutls as! [NSManagedObject]
                {

                    if let username  = r.value(forKey: "username") as? String
                    {listTprint.append(username)
                        listTprint.append("   ")

                    let password = r.value(forKey: "password") as? String
                        listTprint.append(password!)
                        listTprint.append("   ")
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {print("Cannot fetch results")}
        }
        catch {

            print("Error")
        }
       showList.text! = listTprint 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Coredata save fetch update delete
==================================>

import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var my_table: UITableView!

var playerdata = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetch_data = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "PlayerDetails")

    do
    {
        self.playerdata = try context.fetch(fetch_data as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>) as! NSMutableArray

    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.my_table.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return playerdata.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = my_table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hari") as! TableViewCell123

    let playerdetails = self.playerdata[indexPath.row]

    cell.playername.text = (playerdetails as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "player_name")as? String

    cell.playerid.text = (playerdetails as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "player_id")as? String

    cell.playerteam.text = (playerdetails as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "player_team")as? String

    cell.playerimage.image = UIImage(data: ((playerdetails as AnyObject) .value(forKey: "player_img")as? Data)!)

    return cell

}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "datapass", sender: self)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    if(editingStyle == .delete)
    {

        let user = self.playerdata[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject

        context.delete(user)
        do
        {
            try context.save()
            self.playerdata.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)

            my_table.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("error",error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }







}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "datapass"
    {
        let vc2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2

        let index = my_table.indexPathForSelectedRow

        let data = self.playerdata[(index?.row)!]

        vc2.dataupdate = data as! NSManagedObject


    }
}
```

}

VIEWCONTROLLER - 2
===================>
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController2: UIViewController
{

```
@IBOutlet var txt_playername: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var txt_playerid: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var txt_playerteam: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var img_playerimage: UIImageView!

var dataupdate = NSManagedObject()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   if (dataupdate != nil)
    {
        txt_playername.text = dataupdate.value(forKey: "player_name")as? String
        txt_playerid.text = dataupdate.value(forKey: "player_id")as? String
        txt_playerteam.text = dataupdate.value(forKey: "player_team")as? String
        img_playerimage.image = UIImage(data: dataupdate.value(forKey: "player_img") as! Data)

    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func save_update(_ sender: Any)
{
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    if (dataupdate != nil)
    {
        dataupdate.setValue(self.txt_playername.text, forKey: "player_name")
        dataupdate.setValue(self.txt_playerid.text, forKey: "player_id")
        dataupdate.setValue(self.txt_playerteam.text, forKey: "player_team")

         let img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img_playerimage.image!, 1.0)
        dataupdate.setValue(img_data, forKey: "player_img")

    }

    else
    {

    let newplayer = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PlayerDetails", into: context)

    newplayer.setValue(self.txt_playername.text, forKey: "player_name")

    newplayer.setValue(self.txt_playerid.text, forKey: "player_id")

    newplayer.setValue(self.txt_playerteam.text, forKey: "player_team")

    let img_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img_playerimage.image!, 1.0)

    newplayer.setValue(img_data, forKey: "player_img")
    }

    do
    {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)